# Error during export: Mixed update/insert is not supported against the target database yet

Tags: mysql, hadoop, hdfs, sqoop

```
sqoop export --connect "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/retail_db" \
  --driver com.mysql.jdbc.Driver \
  --username root \
  --table departments \
  --export-dir /user/root/departments_export \
  --batch \
  --outdir java_files \
  -m 1 \
  --update-key department_id \
  --update-mode allowinsert
```

Upsert function is not working with MySQL database, regarding this issue got the reason ([link](http://grokbase.com/t/sqoop/user/12a47xzr2a/problem-using-upsert-with-mysql)) but need a solution to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to get rid of `--driver`. My code worked by this way.